# Xamarin Failed to launch app on IOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have got an xamarin forms app that runs perfectly on ios devices (iphone 5s and 4) and all emulators but when i try debug on Iphone6s and Iphone6plus display splash and closing after some seconds.

My app have custom ios maps, pins and location.

Crush Report (Iphone 6s)
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5ff6bbf0814ba7547f9d

(Xcode v7.2 , xamarin forms 2.0.1 , iOS device version 9.2.1)

Comment: "failed to launch after 20.00s" - sounds like something in your AppDelegate is taking too long to spin up, causing iOS to kill the app

Comment: Only 64 bits devices (iphone 6) kill the app ?? I debug in 32 bit devices without problem . Also , i add another first page in my app with one button and next navigate to full logic page but i get the same crush.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved !

I remove Xamarin Insights dlls from project and now app work perfect in all devices.